# How to split decimals and charecter from a string

Tags: vb.net

I need a bit help.
I want to split decimal and character in a string.
Eg : 0.5Lg ---> 0.5 separate and Lg separate.
     0.22Ldd   --->0.22 separate and Ldd Separate

**I tried Following:**

```
    Dim input As String = "0.22Ldd"
    Dim pattern As String = "[^0-9\.]+"
    Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(input, pattern)
    TextBox11.Text = substrings(0)
```

This gives output of 0.22 but how to extract Ldd part?

I tried replacing pattern with "\D+" and "\d+" and "\W+" and [a-zA-Z]+ etc etc after googling but no luck.

Can somebody help. I have googled a lot either output comes along with dot or along with number.

Comment: Did you ever read something about RegEx? This would help to answer your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this LINQ approach:

```
Dim input As String = "0.22Ldd"
Dim numericPart = input.TakeWhile(Function(c) Char.IsPunctuation(c) orelse Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()
Dim number as Decimal
Dim validNumber = Decimal.TryParse(new String(numericPart), NumberStyles.Any, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, number)
Dim letterPart As String = input.Substring(numericPart.Length)
```

Comment: Superb !! Its working fine. I have small doubt. 3rd and 4th is checking only the number is decimal is it ??

Comment: @BharathR: a `Decimal` is a type that accepts numbers which are integers or numbers that have decimal places. So it's the most flexible type

Answer (score 0):

if you want to split them with regex you can try pattern below. Regex.Split gives you matching patterns so you should check for number pattern and text pattern in single regex expression.

```
Dim pattern As String = "([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)"
```